# Modifying a JSON object returned with PDO

Tags: javascript, json, pdo, handlebars.js

I'm trying to return use a JSON object with handlebars. Making a small todo list to learn how to use it.

My PHP API is as follows :

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM table";
try
{
    $db = getConnection();
    $response = $db->query($query);
    $todo = $response->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $bdd = null;
    echo json_encode($todo);
}
```

It then returns something like :

```
[{"id":"1","todo":"Do something","who":"Me","is_done":"0"},{"id":"2","todo":"Learn JSON","who":"Me","is_done":"0"}]
```

But I'd actually need it to be like this :

```
{todos: [{"id":"1","todo":"Do something","who":"Me","is_done":"0"},{"id":"2","todo":"Learn JSON","who":"Me","is_done":"0"}]}
```

I tried in my PHP API to add instead of `echo json_encode($todo)`

```
echo '{todos: ' . json_encode($todo) . '}';
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" => what does it do ?

Comment: When I add it directly in the PHP API, Handlebars.js refuses to parse the resulting json object. In the final HTML I see the "{{title}}".

Comment: you must have " symbol around your todos keyword

Comment: try with `echo '{"todos": ' . json_encode($todo) . '}';`

Comment: Thanks everyone, that did the trick ! I forgot about that. Guess I'll have to go relearn about JSON notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Pointy's answer is correct (might want to read about [JSON](http://json.org/)), alternatively you could do this:

```
echo json_encode(array('todos' => $todo));
```

PHP associative arrays will be serialized to JSON as objects ([json_encode() example in Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#example-3449)).

Answer (score 3):

Your "todos" property name must be quoted with double-quote characters.

```
echo '{"todos": ' . json_encode($todo) . '}';
```

Though JavaScript syntax allows for property names without quotes, strict JSON insists on them.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
 echo '{ "todos" : ' . json_encode($todo) . '}';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo json_encode(array( 'todos' => $todo ));
```

Instead of making the JSON yourself, make the structure you want, then have PHP make the JSON for you.

Comment: Indeed, I'll be using this from now on. Thanks !